# How to rotate a cube about an axis - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, geometry

I am doing an assignment for my course where I need to rotate a cube about a given axis. I can not use MATLAB functions, so I need to do it manually.

This is my attempt that is to no avail.
`

```
function [ CV ] = rotateCubeX( CV, degrees )
    %CV = input vertices/Return val
    %degrees = amount of degrees to rotate
    alpha = degrees * pi/180;
    rotate = zeros(3,3);
    rotate(1,1) = 1;
    rotate(2,2) = cos(alpha);
    rotate(2,3) = -sin(alpha);
    rotate(3,2) = sin(alpha);
    rotate(3,3) = cos(alpha);
    CV = CV * rotate;
    end
```

Before:

```
25.2000 5.9000 2.5000 
25.7000 5.9000 2.5000 
25.7000 7.9000 2.5000 
25.2000 7.9000 2.5000 
25.2000 5.9000 2.8000 
25.7000 5.9000 2.8000 
25.7000 7.9000 2.8000 
25.2000 7.9000 2.8000
```

After:

```
-10.3544 -23.7200 2.5000 
-10.6536 -24.1205 2.5000 
-9.0513 -25.3175 2.5000 
-8.7521 -24.9169 2.5000 
-10.3544 -23.7200 2.8000 
-10.6536 -24.1205 2.8000 
-9.0513 -25.3175 2.8000 
-8.7521 -24.9169 2.8000
```

No change in image.

I am sure I am forgetting something silly.

Comment: So what happens when you run this code, and how does it differ from what you expected to happen?

Comment: This gives no change to the image, but there is slight change to the matrix representing it.

Comment: Yeah there is a significant change in matrices, but not in image

Comment: I edited the additional information into your question.  But you are still leaving out a few details:  what rotation angle did you specify?  What values did you *expect* to see in the output?

Comment: Well I just tested my functions with a different script and they work. So the problem is elsewhere and answering that question would be innapropriate here. So I will work on figuring out the actual question I need to ask. oh dear :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the axis you expect to rotate about? How have you accounted for that in your code?

If you are trying to rotate about an **arbitrary** axis, then the general formula for rotation about an arbitrary axis is [here](http://www.fastgraph.com/makegames/3drotation/).  (look under Other Ways to Build a Rotation Matrix).  Pay attention to handedness and whether you are using row-major or column major matrices!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I now realize my problem. I am rotating about the X axis, when really I want to be rotating about my relative position. (Like if I wanted to move a wheel). So how would I affect my algorithm to do that?

Comment: Ahhh Problem answered! Figured out a work around. I translate whatever object I want to rotate to the origin, then rotate, then translate back.
Problem solved :) Thank you for the brainstorming!